# JavaScript & string length: why is this simple function slow as hell?

Tags: javascript, string-length

i'm implementing a charcounter in the UI, so a user can see how many characters are left for input.

To count, i use this simple function:

```
function typerCount(source, layerID)
{
    outPanel = GetElementByID(layerID);
    outPanel.innerHTML = source.value.length.toString();
}
```

- source contains the field which values we want to meassure
- layerID contains the element ID of the object we want to put the result in (a span or div)
- outPanel is just a temporary var

If i activate this function, while typing the machine really slows down and i can see that FF is using one core at 100%. you can't write fluently because it hangs after each block of few letters.

The problem, it seems, may be the value.length() function call in the second line?

Regards

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle? so we can try alternative methods without having to rewrite a similar script

Comment: Because you use `innerHTML` instead of `document.createTextNode` and because you always call `GetElementById` instead of storing the node variable.

Comment: @john Your alias for `document.getElementById` is `GetElementByID`?

Comment: I suppose that `GetElementById` is the slowest call in this script.

Comment: `value.length` is a property access, not a function call, which means that the only overhead is in resolving the property. There is not enough information in the question to answer. Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? If you don't have a live link we could see, use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com). Does the high CPU usage also occur in other browsers?

Comment: @john Declare the `outPanel` variable. As for now, it's an implicit global...

Comment: Also, why don't you grab `outPanel` once and reuse it? It doesn't _look_ like you should need to query the DOM for that element repeatedly.

Comment: @Arty: i can try that, ok; only GetElementyByID is not a problem, the problem comes up only with second line enabled.

Comment: @Sime: yes, this is a small helper function.

Comment: @john: Howmany times is this method getting called?

Comment: Opera does not show this behaviour.

Comment: @Mahesh: for every key-up, it counts in realtime how many chars the user has entered (same functionality as here on stackoverlow while entering a comment)

Comment: I suspect there is something else going on.  Getting an element by ID is very fast.  And getting a string value, even if a few nesting deep, and setting that the the innerHTML should also be very fast.  What are you using to listen to the key events? Is there anything else listening?

Comment: @johngrinder: See the jsfiddle link. Does it use your CPU a lot? It looks like the problem of CPU usage is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Have you actually profiled the code? Using FireBug or Chrome dev tools?

Comment: @artyom Gosh, `innerText` doesn't work on FF but it looks like you eventually fixed it (after I FIDDLED around for a while :( )

Comment: @Matt: the function is just called by setting OnKeyUp, nothing special here; no other listeners are used. (at least, i haven't acitvated some and since its a self written JS file, there is nothing special in there)

Comment: Arty, this fiddle is OK for me, does use a little CPU power, but i can type fluently. @All: i found out another detail: if i disable CSS files for the site, everything is OK with the counting<->typing speed.

Comment: I played a little bit more with: it really is a problem caused by the CSS description of the layer where the textbox sits in. If i remove all of the CSS code inside the css-file, everything works OK. If i enable the CSS, writing is really slow, as described.

Comment: @Matt,@artyom.stv:  CSS class content is: `.LayerPopupWhite{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: solid 2px #FFFFFF;
    width: 440px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 36%;
    right: 36%;
    top: 45px;
    padding: 10px; 
    z-index:10;
    
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;    
    -khtml-border-radius:7px;  
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;  

 box-shadow: 0 0 30px #202020;   
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #202020;  
 -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 30px#202020;     
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px#202020;
}` But that really strange :-(

Comment: @johngrinder very curious indeed.  If you have the time, cut out those CSS values one by one to see if one (or one type, such as -moz-border-raidus) is the culprit, and let us know.

Comment: @Matt: i've created a jsFiddle here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zhHE7/6/) - interesting: if i rund this small jsfiddle in my FF, it works OK. in Opera its not problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why it's that slow, there's just not enough code in your example to determine that. If you want to count characters in a textarea and limit input to n characters, check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/5dNXZ/). It's fast enough to type without obstruction.

Comment: I tried that fiddle, too; no effect on the problem. See my CSS post/issue above, applies also with the fiddle you posted.

Comment: @johngrinder: then I suppose the problem is something else. Your question doesn't contain enough information to tell you more. I've added the css from your comments on the question to the fiddle, by the way - still not slow. In short: problem can't be reproduced with the provided information.

Comment: @Kooilnc: what i found out, today, is that in other browsers like Opera etc., this problem does not occur... only in FF. Really really strange.

Answer (score 0):

As artyom.stv mentioned in the comments, cache the result of your `GetElementByID` call.  Also, as a side note, what is `GetElementByID` doing?  Is it doing anything else other than calling `document.getElementById`?

How would you cache this you say?

```
var outPanelsById = {};

function getOutPanelById(id) {
    var panel = outPanelsById[id];

    if (!panel) {
         panel = document.getElementById(id);
         outPanelsById[id] = panel;
    }

    return panel;
};

function typerCount(source, layerId) {
    var panel = getOutPanelById(layerId);
    panel.innerHTML = source.value.length.toString();
};
```

I'm thinking there has to be something else going on though, as even `getElementById` calls are extremely fast in FF.

Also, what is "`source`"?  Is it a `DOMElement`?  Or is it something else?

Comment: GetElementID is just a simple wrapper: `function GetElementByID( name )
{
    return document.getElementById( name );
}`

Comment: tried your solution, does not help :-( same behvaiour: cursor is not moving fluently, hangs

Comment: One of your `getElementById`s had improper case, ftfy.

Comment: I'm curious why you are doing this caching....all it does it use a different (smaller) hash table to look up the element by id....I seriously doubt that is significantly faster than just using getElementById directly, especially if you take into account function call overhead, the if statement, etc.  Just seems like a lot of extra complexity for very little benefit.

Comment: rob, you are right, it probably isn't a huge benefit.  I was just taking a stab.

Answer (score 0):

It could be having problems with outPanel. Every time you call that function, it will look up that DOM node. If you are targeting the same DOM node, that's very expensive for the browser if it's doing that every single time you type a character.

Also, this is too verbose:

```
source.value.length.toString();
```

This is sufficient:

```
source.value.length;
```

JavaScript is dynamic. It doesn't need the conversion to a string.

Comment: while caching is, in general, a good practice, getting an element by ID is very fast, and likely not the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your problem is with the use of innerHTML or getElementById().

I would try to isolate the problem by removing parts of the function and seeing how the cpu is used.  For instance, try it all these ways:

```
var len;

function typerCount(source, layerID)
{
    len = source.value.length;
}

function typerCount(source, layerID)
{
    len = source.value.length.toString();
}

function typerCount(source, layerID)
{
    outPanel = GetElementByID(layerID);
    outPanel.innerHTML = "test";
}
```